# Where did St. Thomas Aquinas say Mary approached the borders of the Hypostatic Union?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, reference-request, thomas-aquinas, hypostatic-union

Where did St. Thomas Aquinas say Mary approached the borders/fringes of the divinity or Hypostatic Union?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I've been able to find, his sermon [*On the Angelic Salutation*](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/62095/1787) (Lent 1273):

> She Herself [was] more holy than anyone after Christ.
> <sub>Ipsa (Virgo) [fuit] magis quam alius sanctus, praeter Christum.</sub>